# Issues with CurrencyConverter qml tutorial

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I'm trying to follow the tutorial at https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/apps/qml/tutorials/building-your-first-qml-app/ which states, "Select the Projects > Ubuntu > App with Simple UI template and click Choose…". However when I start a new project I am given a choice of three "Simple UI", which are

"QML APP with Simple UI(cmake)"
"QML App with Simple UI(qmlproject)"
"QML App with Simple UI(qmake)"

I'm not sure which one to pick and they all seem to have issues. So which one should I use?
Thanks,
Barry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the third one "QML App with Simple UI(qmake)". I also discovered I needed to change
"import QtQuick 2.4" to "import QtQuick 2.0"
and "import Ubuntu.Components 1.3" to "import Ubuntu.Components 1.1".
Now it seems to work OK. I hope this will help some one else.

Barry

Comment: 2.4 and 1.3 work fine for me on Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: @ moritz  That's interesting, I'm using 14.04. I wonder what I installed wrong, if anything. Anyone have any Ideas?